# Is this vinyl tile? Should I have it tested for asbestos?

Tags: tile, adhesive, removal, asbestos

What kind of tile is this? I think it is vinyl tile but it doesn't look like the pictures I am finding online. Maybe it is plastic tile?

The house is from the 1950s but the bathroom was installed prior to 1990.

Should I be concerned about asbestos?

The tile is 1/8 inch thick and 12" by 12". It doesn't break with pulling it up. The adhesive is tacky and difficult to remove.

[image]

Comment: That looks like ceramic with the glass like chips.

Comment: It feels like plastic. It bends a little. Is that possible with a ceramic? Thanks

Comment: If it bends it is not ceramic tile. Without professional analysis you will not be able to ascertain whether it is/has asbestos. Call a professional abatement contractor or do it yourself (if legal in your locale) using all appropriate asbestos handling precautions, just in case.

Comment: There are asbostes test kits avabial way cheaper since this looks like cheramic or porcelain tiles and the timeline you suggest I would doubt it is asbestos you already have chipped some of it up. I have only seen porcelain and ceramic tiles since the 70's and the earlier asbestos tiles were nothing like this.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose I should update this with what I learned. I got a test done and the tiles did not contain asbestos but the mastic below the tiles did. The mastic was from a previously installed floor.